# DEM disappears at certain zoom level in browser

Tags: dem, qgis2threejs

my Qgis2threejs-model looks fine in the plug-in window, but in the browser (e.g. Edge) I have to zoom out to see the DEM. If I zoom in the DEM desappears at a certain zoom level. I don't want this behaviour.
Is there a parameter in any of the js-files, to define this zoom level or even to switch it off?

QGIS 3.4.13 and qgis2threejs 2.3

Kind regards!

[image: DEM in plug-in and browser window[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InjmV.png)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved in plug-in 2.4.1